# Consolidate light and lights tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

I was looking at a recent question which was migrated from another Stack. The question had to do with LED lights. While looking to retag it, I noticed there is a [light](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) and a [lights](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lights) tags. This seems redundant. Both tags have many questions associated with them, but I'm thinking they should be combined and one purged. I think the proper one to keep would be [lights](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lights), but before I do, I'm looking for feedback from our esteemed members.

Comment: I've merged [tag:light] into [tag:lights]. There were 28 questions which were moved over.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to agree on [lights](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lights): it has more associated questions and has some descriptive text.

Comment: agree with that.